# The program I am running runs just fine, but when debugging it will give an error

Tags: attributeerror, smb

[Debugger Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at4s2.png)

The program I am running runs just fine, but when debugging it will give an error. It will give an error at line: from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
I am unsure where to start, and can provide further information as needed.

I am trying to debug a program and cannot get past:
AttributeError: '_ModuleLock' object has no attribute 'name'